# Как загуглить, чтобы найти информацию о дереве, в котором корень - это минимальное число?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дерево сравнивает левую и правую часть и все время находит самую маленькую часть( корень будет самым маленьким и в каждом подерве корень снова будет самым маленьким, но больше корня) Это рекурсивное дерево или у него есть другие называния?

Answer (score 4):

Если верно понял, то вы имеете ввиду heap sort/Двоичная куча/Пирамидальная сортировка. Там есть как поиск максимума так и минимума.

Comment: да, это оно )) спасибо ))

Comment: это все одно и тоже дерево ?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, как применять B дерево и красно-черное дерево